# How to fix I/O error 102, When Assigning a file

Tags: file, delphi, assign

My teacher assigned me to create a simple project: Create a form, which the user has to complete and when he presses the submit button, then the program should write all the information in different textfiles (For example, 1 textfile for their first name, onother for their last name etc.) (I know it sounds insane, but a project is a project). Anyway, I tried this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);   //On Click
var 
F:Array[1..20]of textfile;                        //20 fields, 1 txt each one
Firstname,Fname:string;                           //Location,Field

Begin
Firstname:=ExtractFilePath(Paramstr(0))+'User\Identity\FirstName.txt'; //Location
Fname:=Edit1.text;

AssignFile(f[1],Firstname);
Rewrite(f[1],Firstname);
writeln(f[1],Fname);
closefile(f[1]);
end;
```

I searched on the Google about this error:

> I/O error 102,

All I found is that Delphi does not assign the file, for some reasons. But I still don't get why, the code looks absolutely correct and logical to me, Perhaps what I tried:

> F:Array[1..20]of Textfile is wrong, the only reason i tried it, is because i wanted to start writing f1,f2,...,f20

What do you think I should do?

Comment: The second argument of `Rewrite` should **not** be `Firstname`. Does it even compile? Also, you need to spend more time on chosing good variable names. `Firstname` is the path to the file containing the first name, and `Fname` is the first name. Not good.

Comment: No, it is correct...even if i change it, the error will be raised

Comment: No, it is definitely **not** correct. Trust me. A string as second argument of `Rewrite` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: So i should just leave it as it is? F[1]?

Comment: Yes, for textfile I believe so (been a while since I used old-school Pascal I/O, though).

Comment: @user2296565, there is no point of having array of files unless you do some I/O on them on simultaneous basis.

Comment: @user539484 is actually right. You could use a single `f` variable and reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `Rewrite` should not be a string. Does it even compile? There shouldn't be a second argument at all, IIRC. Do you have write access to the directory? Does the directory even exist? I don't think the RTL will create it for you. If this is indeed your problem, simply do

```
ForceDirectories(ExtractFilePath(FileName)); // FileName=Firstname
```

prior to calling `Assign`.

Comment: Because I....Have no idea about it, my teacher is speciallized in older versions of delphi and pascal, such as turbo pascal, and this is the only method i know...Where can i find the TstringList method?

Comment: `TStringList` isn't a method. It's a class, and one that has always been very central to Delphi programming. For instance, the `Items` property of a `TComboBox` or `TListBox`, the `Lines` property of a `TMemo` or `TRichEdit`, and so on, are all `TStringList`s (essentially). So you have already used this class a lot in your previous questions!

Comment: Ok thank you, Andreas...Can i also use this when writing in console application?

Comment: @user2296565: You should know that old-school Pascal is deprecated, and shouldn't be used in new applications. There are a number of reasons for this. First, the `FileMode` is a global variable, and so two threads cannot have different modes. Second, Unicode support is somewhat awkward using Pascal I/O.

Comment: @user2296565: Of course. `TStringList` can be used everywhere.

Comment: There is no advantage in your advice to rewrite code with `TStrings`. Disadvantage might be present since it is a student's assignment.

Comment: @user539484: Except for the things I mentioned, and it's IMHO easier with `TStrings`. But I don't care. I remove it.